# Case Insensitive sorting using Google Guava

Tags: java, sorting, guava

Current I am using the following 2 pieces of code in 2 different places to create a sorted, immutable list.

```
return Ordering.natural().immutableSortedCopy(iterable);
```

and

```
return Ordering.usingToString().immutableSortedCopy(machines);
```

However, this makes the 'ordering' case **sensitive**.

How do I use the guava apis to make a case-**insensitive** sorted immutable list?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe you will need to use the [from](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#from%28java.util.Comparator%29) method with the `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` comparator, like this.

```
return Ordering.from(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER).immutableSortedCopy(iterable);
```

Comment: ok this seems to work when using Ordering.natural, however I have another place where I use Ordering.usingToString().immutableSortedCopy(), how will it work in this case?

Comment: `from` takes any comparator. In the `toString` case you would need to create your own comparator and do something like `toString().toLowerCase()` before comparing. Cheers!

Comment: For the `usingToString()` replacement, I would compose your `Ordering` with `Functions.toStringFunction()`, e.g. `return Ordering.from(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER).onResultOf(Functions.toStringFunction()).immutableSortedCopy(iterable);`